# How to increment progressively the margin left using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an image of a black cat
I want to progressively increase its width and also make the image moving from left to right increasing its own left margin. 
I can't understand why the width is increased and the margin-left shows `NaN value`.

**Down here the Html :-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Cat Walk</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="cat-gif" style="position:absolute;" src="http://www.anniemation.com/clip_art/images/cat-walk.gif">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Down here the function to make move the cat:-**

```
var catWalk = function() {

var cat = document.getElementById("cat-gif");

cat.setAttribute('width', cat.width+10); //THIS WORKS
cat.setAttribute('marginLeft', cat.marginLeft+10); //THIS DOES NOT WORK!

}

//Call to the function
window.setInterval(catWalk, 500);
```

Comment: Because an mage element has a `width` property, but not a `marginLeft` property. Your are not actually manipulating _styles_ here, but only HTML element attributes/properties. `cat.marginLeft` was undefined to begin with, and so your attempt of adding 10 to _that_ of course does not result in an actual number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the following:

```
cat.style.marginLeft = (parseInt((cat.style.marginLeft) || parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(cat).marginLeft))) + 10 + 'px';
```

instead of `cat.setAttribute('marginLeft', cat.marginLeft+10);` there is no attribute marginLeft by default on your Element. So you gotta go by getting the computed styles and add it to your style attribute then you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Margin left is not a  attribute hence it does not work in your case.
its a style property hence you need to do it differently
replace

```
cat.setAttribute('marginLeft', cat.marginLeft+10);
```

with

```
var p = cat.style.marginLeft; // return value in px; i.e 50px
p = p.substr(0,p.length-2); // remove px ie : 50px becomes 50
cat.style.marginLeft = (+p)+ 10 +'px' // convert p to number and add 10
```