# How to move a div with a timer?

Tags: javascript, move

I tested with `console.log{"test")` and it wrote multiple times so I know the timing works but the div won't move!

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 100);

function myTimer() {
  var carre = document.getElementById("carre");
  carre.style.marginLeft = carre.style.marginLeft + "10px";
}
```

```html
<div id="carre" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: _`carre.style.marginLeft + "10px"`_ — `carre.style.marginLeft` is already a string with `px` at the end. Concatenating it makes it invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment progressively the margin left using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081571/how-to-increment-progressively-the-margin-left-using-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't add a string ("10px") to the end of another string and expect it to treat that as a mathematical operation. Neither value is numeric.

This will work:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 100);

function myTimer() {
  var carre = document.getElementById("carre");
  if (carre.style.marginLeft == "") {
    carre.style.marginLeft = "10px";
  } else {
    carre.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(carre.style.marginLeft) + 10) + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="carre" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, yeah that was stupid to think i can add a text  value to the left property.i worked once so i thought it should work

Comment: `parseInt(carre.style.marginLeft)` is enough. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` can deal with leading whitespace and anything after the actual number.

Comment: @Thomas that's true, I forgot that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes.

- You need to `parseInt` to convert `marginLeft` to number because it returns number with `px`.
- Secondly you should add only `10` without `""` and add `"px"` at the end.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 100);

function myTimer() {
  var carre = document.getElementById("carre");
  console.log()
  carre.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(carre.style.marginLeft)||0) + 10 + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id="carre" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;position:absolute;"></div>
```